# Get the index of each item in a loop

Tags: c#

I have a datatable and I am doing operations on it to take the result like this:

```
var result = from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
             select new
             {
                 Campaign = grp.Key,
                 Count = grp.Count(),
                 SL = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<Decimal>("Inb.ServiceLevel"))
             };
```

I want to loop on that `result`

I tried these two ways:

#### First

```
for (int i=0;i< result.Count(); i++){
{
}
```

but I couldn't type `result[i].Count`

#### second

```
foreach (var item in result)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LINQ expression returns an IEnumerable, which cannot be accessed through an indexer. This is why `result[i]` in your first attempt does not work.

The fix is simple: Convert your IEnumerable to a List:

```
var result = (from ... select new { ... }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
         group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
         select new
         {
             Campaign = grp.Key,
             Count = grp.Count(),
             SL = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<Decimal>("Inb.ServiceLevel"))
         }).ToList();

if(result.Count() > 0)
{
  ///Do Something//// 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? Use for instead.

Anyway, if you insist, you can create an extension function that will provide this functionallity. Something like this:

```
   public static void ForEachIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (T curr in collection)
        {
            action(curr, index);
            index++;
         }
    }
```

Usage:

```
List<int> collection = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
int output = 0;
collection.ForEachIndex((curr,idx) => output += curr * idx);
```